# Should this question about changing color settings in Google Colab remain open or be closed?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, scope

While reviewing First Posts, I came across an audit regarding this question ([how to change theme in google colab?? I need dark theme like Jupyter notebook has](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49894993/how-to-change-theme-in-google-colab-i-need-dark-theme-like-jupyter-notebook-ha)). I  believe that the post is blatantly off-topic. Contrary to my expectations, the question isn't closed. Nevertheless, here are some convicting reasons why I believe the question should be closed:

1. Question is tagged with [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) an [python-3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x). But no code or further mention of Python is apparent anywhere on the Q&A.
2. Question is tagged with Theme. But the content seems far removed from how other [theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/theme) questions are asked.

Looking at the [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49894993/timeline) of the question, there was initially a close vote but this became invalidated shortly. There were also 3 downvotes, but these were swamped with 17 upvotes over time.

What concerns me is that the question and answers are fairly recent. (Asked on April 2018, Accepted Answer posted on February 2019.) So I'm guessing either

1. I have a misunderstanding of what qualifies as on-topic, *or*
2. The question was lucky enough to dodge the eagle eyes of the community's more vigilant persons.

<sup>(I know this a false dichotomy but bear with me.)</sup>

The [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) help page asserts that questions related to "*software tools commonly used by programmers*" are generally on-topic. Now I'm more confused.

**Should the question be closed? Otherwise, is my judgement faulty?**

Comment: What is the distinction that you draw between "a support site" and Stack Overflow? Also, why are you so confused by the guidance in the Help Center that indicates questions about "software tools commonly used by programmers" are indeed on-topic?

Comment: Seems like a gray area (or darkly themed at least). Bug tracker usage generally would be on-topic, but changing the theme is stretching it a bit IMO.

Comment: I don't know. I understand the "used for development" angle. But it's not like if the question is a programming-related. It seems like a general technical support question, I could also see how the question would fall under [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-cant-i-ask-customer-service-related-questions).

Comment: It's okay.  Would be nice if programmers knew how to adjust their monitor brightness but that's a lost art.

Comment: @CodyGray Perhaps I drew too much attention to that sentence, but it was extraneous so I've removed it. Regarding your second question, having drifted around the community for a while, I feel that questions without much ties to programming are off-topic. I don't know... it's just rare to see something relatively distant from the topic of programming that I feel like I had to ask here.

Comment: Regarding the audit-part, since apparently the question received several down-votes and close votes since you got it as an audit, it's likely to be removed from the audit pool at least.

Comment: `I strongly believe that the post is blatantly off-topic` - @TrebledJ, What makes you think an ide is not related to programming?. All ide related theme questions are well received here.. [visual studio](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14050561/219933), [Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16601260), [VS Code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53951652/219933) , [Netbeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21042861/dark-theme-in-netbeans-7-or-8). Dont tell me you use [vim](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2975994/219933) either.

Comment: @MatJ Most other questions tend to have code in them, so I'm probably somewhat biased to seeing those types of questions. Other than that, the question could be cleaned up (should be trivial though), and just that it _seemed_ lowish-mid quality probably played on my opinions.
On the other hand, I wasn't aware of those other ide-theme questions, thanks for pulling those up.

Comment: I believe the question is on-topic for the reason you have mentioned in your post ( _software tools commonly used by programmers_ ). As for the tags, you should have edited them out if they weren't relevant. Also, the close reason now, ( _recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource_ ) is misleading as that question doesn't ask for any recommendations. I've edited the post to make it better.

Answer (score -2):

No, the question should not be closed.

As you said in the OP, tools used for software development are on topic on Stack Overflow.

The reasoning is that the audience is the developer community, since they are the ones using them. On Super User there would be fewer people that know the answer.

Comment: No, questions abou tools used for software development **can be** on topic, they are not on-topic by definition.

Comment: @Gibby: So what makes this one off topic in your opinion?

Comment: I would suggest that questions about software are on topic **iff** it is about how to use the software for programming-related tasks. Changing the theming of software is not at all related to programming.